# ReactJS - Clear localStorage on tab/browser close but not on refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser

i want to clear local  storage on tab close not on refresh

Is there a way to detect tab close event to clear the localStorage. I need localStorage to share data across tabs. window.onbeforeunload event works fine but it has 2 issues for me:

It also fires on page refresh which I dont want.
i also try windw.onCLose but not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think its wise to use sessionStorage(window.sessionStorage) rather than localStorage because it automatically clears the data after closing browser or tab.

And for `window.onbeforeunload`, you can't prevent this event on page refresh.